# Given the alternating series. . . what is the infinite sum of . . .

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, alternating-expression

"What is the infinite sum of the alternating series?"

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \, (5 \pi)^{2n+1}}{6^{2n+1} \, (2n+1)!}$$

This problem was given to me along with the $\cos(x)$ series, and I know that the answer is $\dfrac{1}{2}$, just not how to get there.

I have tried plugging in $5 \pi$ for $x$, but then from there, I don't know how to compensate for the $6^{2n+1}$ in the denominator to get the full sum.

All help is welcome! Thank you!

Comment: As it happens, the series you want is that for $\sin(x)$, not $\cos(x)$.

Comment: @PrincessEev sin would be $ x + x^3 / 3! $ ... no? I'm still not following I'm sorry

Comment: $\sin(x)$ is alternating;

$$\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} x^{2k+1}$$

What you have is for $\sinh(x)$.

Comment: @PrincessEev so the $6^{2n+1} $ comes from just multiplying by $1/6^{2n+1} $ ? I see now that it's actually sinx, but how could I solve the sum?

Comment: Hint: instead of thinking $x=5\pi$, think $x=5\pi/6$.

Comment: @GregMartin and I understand lol. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can answer your question by re-writing your sum as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n(\frac {5π} 6)^{2n+1}} {(2n+1)!}$$
by moving the $6^{2n+1}$ into the denominator into the $(5π)^{2n+1}$ in the numerator as they have the same exponent and then immediately noticing that this is the Mclaurin series for sin(x) evaluated at $x= \frac{5π}{6}$.

We know that $\frac{5π} {6} = π - \frac {π}{6}$, so using the identity $\sin(a-b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) - \cos(a) \sin(b)$ we can evaluate the sin($\frac{5π}{6}$) as follows: $$\sin(\frac{5π}{6})  = \sin(π - \frac {π}{6}) = \sin(π) \cos(\frac {π}{6}) - \cos(π) \sin(\frac {π}{6}) = 0 - (-1)(\frac {1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I just emailed my professor because the problem is what really threw me off here. They said that this was the maclauren series for cosx, and even the answer is wrong in the answer sheet. I put 1/2, but I think they were asking for -root(3)/2.

Comment: Oh, ok. I understand. I also get confused between the Taylor series of the cos(x) and sin(x), but I'm glad that you knew beforehand. What helps me to differentiate between them is by remembering that cos(x) is an even function - so I associate that with the even exponentials in each of the terms of its Mclaurin series, and that sin(x) is an odd function - so it must have odd exponentials in its Mclaurin series.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm remembering it! lol.